# Unable to get proxychains to accept HTTPS setting, but it does accept HTTP

Tags: linux, https, proxy

I'm testing out using proxychains using a couple of free proxy servers and have the config file setup like this:

```
proxychains curl ifconfig.me/ip
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
error: invalid item in proxylist section: https 45.15.168.190   8888
```

When I try calling a network call via proxychains it throws this error:

```
$ proxychains curl ifconfig.me/ip
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
error: invalid item in proxylist section: https 45.15.168.190   8888
```

If I delete the HTTPS line, and call the same thing it returns without issue:

```
└─$ proxychains curl ifconfig.me/ip
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] Strict chain  ...  45.15.168.238:8888  ...  ifconfig.me:80  ...  OK
45.15.168.238
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Proxchains only support the following type connections: http, socks4 socks5

````
# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#           http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )```
````